# Debian wlan0 interface not found

Tags: wireless-networking, debian-wheezy, wifi-configuration

I have troubles to configure my wireless card in Debian Wheezy. I followed the instruction from: https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi

It is a fresh debian install, before this i ran Ubuntu but because I had some troubles with it (not wireless related problems) I decided to give Debian wheezy a try.

Note: Wireless worked out of the box running the latest Ubuntu version.

Before installed the Debian I checked my wireless card it told me it was:

```
8086:0083 Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]
```

Note: internal wireless card on laptop: Dell XPS L502x

this card is also in the list of supported devices, so i installed Debian, installed the iwlwifi module. that enabled the 'Wireless' tab at the network manager. But iwconfig tells me that there is no wlan0 interface found.

so i ran `lspci -nn | grep Wireless` on the debian terminal and it stated: (see the difference to the numbers in the beginning)

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak] [8086:0083]
```

output: `rfkill list all` (i had to install rfkill first, maybe it is a sign more is missing? )

```
$> rfkill list all
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

when i ran `iwconfig`, `ifconfig` or `ip addr` these interfaces are shown:

```
eth0 (currently working on)
lo (loopback)
```

ouput: `ifconfig -a`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 84:8f:69:ae:44:5a  
          inet addr:192.168.178.29  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::868f:69ff:feae:445a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2465 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2093 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1922631 (1.8 MiB)  TX bytes:255361 (249.3 KiB)
          Interrupt:41 Base address:0x6000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:480 (480.0 B)  TX bytes:480 (480.0 B)
```

output of:  `dmesg | grep Wireless`

```
[    6.686069] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux, in-tree:
[    6.686694] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) 
Wireless-N 1000 BGN, REV=0x6C
```

Do i have to manually 'start' the wireless card before it is able to scan the networks? Do you have any suggestions for me to make it work?

Comment: Have you tried `ipconfig all`? If so, post the output here.

Comment: @redbeam_ I added the information you requested, thanks for helping ;)

Comment: My last guess is: `ipconfig wlan0 up`

Comment: The interface (wlan0) it not even known/recognized in the system so I think there is no need to put it 'up' or 'down'. Of course I tried but is didn't help. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved!

i had to install the following package: firmware-iwlwifi (0.36+wheezy.1) [non-free]

Link: https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/firmware-iwlwifi
Rebooted and Voilla!

Comment: works for `buster` too, https://packages.debian.org/buster/firmware-iwlwifi

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes some motherboard needs a dkms to work with the MoBo. Some years ago we have to install it with the source. Now it is available in the repo to handle all the hassle. You can search with `apt search dkms` and then install the required dkms. And then it starts to work.